# Ubuntu broke my Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, sound, windows

I have Windows 10 on my laptop, i decided that i would like to dual-boot it with ubuntu (this was my first time installing ubuntu onto any device/ or any linux-based system).

Made my USB Bootable, went through the installation process choose the option to dual-boot, everything seemed to be fine, my pc restarted to finish installation (after it went off I took out my usb) then it booted directly to windows, so I shut down my computer pressed f12, and I just saw the windows boot manager in the options, the I did the same thing with my usb plugged on, and now I see the windows boot manager, the usb for installing ubuntu, and an unknown device(that was grub btw) after looking for a few fixes couldn't get anything to repair that, figured out that i just installed grub into the usb, i gave up and deleted the partition that had ubuntu.

Now it's where my problems really started, i had no sound, my drivers were perfect it detected the speakers and everything but it simply didn't play sound couldn't play test tone, same thing for audio input, and camera, also i am unable to go into services.msc, now chrome closes itself from time to time, i cannot use the reset option nor update, it's a nightmare.

Then i reinstalled Ubuntu to test if it would have problems too, it was perfect actually it had sound input/output, it would detect my camera everything was fine except that i couldn't get grub to boot first.

Then i tried everything, boot-repair, moving partitions, literally everything that a normal user could do so i just uninstalled ubuntu again to see if ubuntu was "sucking the periphericals or something" and im still without clue to what to do.

Right now i just want my W10 back to normal, i won't be trying to install ubuntu again until i have some partition knowledge, so if someone could help me out to get my windows back to normal it would be great.

EDIT 1:

When i tried to open the setup for windows 10 this happens:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/047pF.png) thing pops up for a few minutes everything fine

then [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqT0Q.png) and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to settings.

[image: settings]

2. Search for 'Reset this PC'
3. Reset the PC

[image: reset the pc]

If this doesn't work, download the Windows ISO and install windows again

Comment: Actually, as i said in the question, i am unable to reset my pc.

Comment: It goes trought the process and randomly gives an error like "Something happened while trying to reset your pc" and it just restarts it and goes back to windows just as i left it.

Comment: Can you make a USB bootable windows 10 and re install the same??

Comment: I tried to create one, trough the windows media creation tool, it randomly close, im going to try it a second time, and if it dosen't work proceed with doing it on another computer